# js Отслеживание добавления нового элемента в DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть список ul#list. Нужно отслеживать добавление новых li в этот список.

Сейчас делаю через таймер. Но время добавления всегда слишком разное, и потому через таймер не совсем некорректно. Скрипт будет работать постоянно, потому хотелось бы по минимуму использовать ресурсы.

**Доступа к скрипту, который добавляет элементы в список - нету**

Есть ли в js подобное событие?

Comment: А как так получается, что доступа к скрипту нету?

Comment: @tutankhamun Очень просто, это userscript

Comment: можно подробнее? Что-то я не понял. Если владеете английским, то есть на SO вот такой вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom. Там информации вагон

Answer (score 1):

Есть события из группы DOM Mutation Events:

- DOMSubtreeModified
- DOMNodeInserted
- DOMNodeRemoved
- DOMCharacterDataModified
- DOMAttrModified

Про них можно почитать (по английски)

- [W3 UI Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) - описание событий (кстати тут написано, что они уже устаревшие и взамен идет механизм `MutationObserver`, но поддержка всеми текущими браузерами наступит наверняка несколько позже)
- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Также можно "пощупать" их в действии в разных браузерах
  - [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events/DOMtree.html)

Answer (score 1):

Если элемент добавляется через `.appendChild()` или эквивелантную функцию, можно использовать событие `DOMNodeInserted`, как в примере ниже. Если добавляется, например, через `node.innerHTML += "<li>элемент</li>"`, то без таймера никак.

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");

var n = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  n++;
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerHTML = "элемент " + n;
  list.appendChild(item);
}, 2500);

list.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
  alert("элемент добавлен.");
}, false);
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>элемент 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно привязать событие DOMNodeInserted к элементу

```js
$('#my_but').click(function(){$('<li>nuw item</li>').appendTo($('#list'))});
$('#list').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    alert('element: ' + e.target + ' was inserted');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id = "list">
  <li>old data</li>
  <li>old data</li>
  <li>old data</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id = "my_but">Click Me!</button>
```